# RTK Query correct way to map props with transformResponse

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm working on linking up a scheduler component with data that I am receiving through an RTK Query api call. In order for the scheduler to work, I have to adjust the prop names to names the scheduler utilizes, before the state is available in the component (otherwise it does not load when I've tried in the React component). There is not a clear example of this being done in the RTK Query docs (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-query-responses-with-transformresponse) , but it seems like it should be possible. When I've implemented it, the query gets fulfilled, but comes back as an empty object, or an array with a single empty object depending on how I've tried to structure it.

```
getUserScheduleVisits: builder.query({
            query: userId => `/visitapi/visits/users/${userId}`,
            providesTags: ['Visit', 'User'],
            transformResponse: (response) => {
                return {
                    data: [{
                        id: response._id,
                        startDate: response.visitStart,
                        endDate: response.visitEnd,
                        title: response?.client?.fullName
                    }]
                }
            },
        }),
```

When I've run the query without the transform response, the data comes through as expected, however remains unusable by the Scheduler component I'm trying to implement. I'm still learning the complexities to RTK Query so I'm sure its how I'm trying to use transformResponse, I'm just not sure how to approach it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would end up as `result.data.data` if you do `const result = useMyQuery()`.

Did you maybe mean to do this?

```
getUserScheduleVisits: builder.query({
            query: userId => `/visitapi/visits/users/${userId}`,
            providesTags: ['Visit', 'User'],
            transformResponse: (response) => {
                return [{
                        id: response._id,
                        startDate: response.visitStart,
                        endDate: response.visitEnd,
                        title: response?.client?.fullName
                    }]
            },
        }),
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly got me 1 step closer, the object being returned has the correct fields, but comes back undefined. When I remove the transformResponse I get the expected data, so is there a step missing to map the props over to the new field names?

Comment: Have you tried logging both `response` and the value that you are returning from this function? Maybe an assumption there is wrong?

Comment: Response logs the expected data before the transform, based on your answer I had a thought to try response.data.visitStart, etc., but that crashes the page as truly undefined, rather than just undefined values.

Comment: I mean to a `transformResponse: (response) => { const myReturnValue = [ ...your code ...  ]; console.log(myReturnValue); return myReturnValue }`. You are building an object here that does not have the values you want. Also. Do you explicitly **want** to build an array with one element here?

Comment: That was the issue I was facing (I'm self taught and for some reason arrays confuse my brain) but from your suggestions I was able to get it working properly with: transformResponse: (response) => { return  response.map((response) => ( { definitions: response.values}). I appreciate you taking the time to help me think that through. I really do find RTK Query immensely useful, its just the limits of my understanding that get me stuck. Thanks again!